# What is preventing this animation from being automatic?

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, slider

My client wants this "sponsors" slider on their site to either scroll, be randomized or fade in and fade out. I've tried different things to make all of these happen, but nothing works.  Right now the slider is controlled by buttons set to a ".click" command. Is there a way to add animation with Javascript and what do I need to change to make this happen? If not animation, is there a way to randomize the array on the page load with Javascript? I keep trying to input different changes, but nothing is working. I feel like maybe I need to "turn other things off" to make them work...

I'm new to Javascript though, so I would appreciate some help.

Here is the code:

```
// ============
// = SPONSORS =
// ============

if($('#sponsors').length>0){

    // let's make sure our logos are centered
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#sponsor-logos li').each(function(){
            wrapper = $(this).find('span.logo');
            wrapper_height = wrapper.height();
            sponsor_logo = $(this).find('img');
            total_height = 84;
            logo_height = sponsor_logo.height();
            buffer = Math.floor(((total_height - logo_height) / 2));
            wrapper.css('paddingTop',buffer + 'px').height(wrapper_height-buffer);
        });
    });

    window_width = 656;
    slide_duration = 500;


    // get our arrows on there
    $('#sponsors .inner').prepend('<a class="prev" href="#">Prev</a>').append('<a class="next" href="#">Next</a>');

    // set our width
    thumbs = $('#sponsor-logos');
    thumbs.width(thumbs.children().length*164);
    thumbs.wrap('<div class="slider"></div>');




    // hook the arrows
    $('#sponsors  a.prev').click(function(){
        thumbs = $('#sponsor-logos');
        if((Math.abs(parseInt(thumbs.css('left').replace('px',''),10)))>1){
            if(!thumbs.data('animating')){
                thumbs.data('animating',true);
                thumbs.animate(
                        {left:'+='+window_width+'px'},
                        slide_duration, 'swing', function(){
                            thumbs.data('animating',false);
                        }
                    );
            }
        }else{
            // already too far, we'll bounce for feedback
            if(!thumbs.data('animating')){
                thumbs.data('animating',true);
                thumbs.animate(
                        {left:'+=15px'},
                        (slide_duration/5), 'swing', function(){
                            thumbs.animate(
                                    {left:'-=15px'},
                                    (slide_duration/5), 'swing', function(){
                                        thumbs.data('animating',false);
                                    }
                                );
                        }
                    );
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('#sponsors a.next').click(function(){
        thumbs = $('#sponsor-logos');
        if(thumbs.width() - window_width - Math.abs(parseInt(thumbs.css('left').replace('px',''),10)) > 150){ // 150 represents at least one thumb (194 to be exact)
            if(!thumbs.data('animating')){
                thumbs.data('animating',true);
                thumbs.animate(
                        {left:'-='+window_width+'px'},
                        slide_duration, 'swing', function(){
                            thumbs.data('animating',false);
                        }
                    );
            }
        }else{
            // already too far, we'll bounce for feedback
            if(!thumbs.data('animating')){
                thumbs.data('animating',true);
                thumbs.animate(
                        {left:'-=15px'},
                        (slide_duration/5), 'swing', function(){
                            thumbs.animate(
                                    {left:'+=15px'},
                                    (slide_duration/5), 'swing', function(){
                                        thumbs.data('animating',false);
                                    }
                                );
                        }
                    );
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

}
```

Comment: Within `$('#sponsor-logos li').each()`, you're declaring variables as implied globals. You probably ought to be declaring them using var: `var wrapper = $(this).find('span.logo'), …, buffer = …;` (use a comma to separate each new variable and end your declaration block with a semicolon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sort of looks like you might have modified the script of a pre-fabricated jquery image slider. If that is the case, you are very likely going about this the hard way. Ordinarily you include the provided script in your header, then in your html file, point it to an element in your DOM, like

```
$("#galleryContainerElement").imgSlider({ object:of, slider:preferences });
```

If you're having trouble with a specific slider, please let us know which one.

If you are not already, I would advising using a slider like [Orbit](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider) (it's now part of Zurb's *Foundation* framework, but you can download it separately). Alternatively, there are dozens upon dozens of sliders built on jQuery, and most are easy to configure if you're at all familiar with jQuery.

If you'd rather reinvent the wheel, jQuery has an [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function (which is used a few times in the code you provided). You would need use either a [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) or [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function that you trigger onload / document.ready, and the functions declared in `$('#sponsors a.prev').click()` and `$('#sponsors a.next').click()` should be moved out so you can recycle them. I'm a little less inclined to walk thru writing your own slider given that so many already exist.

Side-note: Please be aware that w3schools is in no way affiliated with the W3C; I reference them here because their examples are straight-forward.

Comment: I just realized I never thanked you for this thorough answer. In the end I wound up going with another slider. Thank you for steering me in the right direction!

Comment: @Bana, you're welcome :) would you approve this as an answer so the question can close?